# Swift package - accessing main app without importing it?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-package-manager

I'm fairly new to swift and working on a project where it has a main monolith app and has started to split off the project in modules using swift package manager. My question is what is the best way to access certain classes, types, protocols that live in the main monolith app from the package module? Can't import the global main app since that defeats the purpose of modularisation but not entirely sure how I can access those objects. Appreciate the help in understanding this.

Comment: Your main app is a `centralized object` and your package module is independent, means it could work with any `centralize object`. Each modules should have `gate` to push data in and get data out. Some interfaces would work well, don't import any library from your monolith app.

Comment: You don’t access your main app from the library in any way, never. Maybe you need to move those classes into your library or maybe you need another library because one library can import another library.